# Jquery hiding responsive navigation when increasing browser size

Tags: jquery, css

I have a nav bar that hides when the window goes below a certain width. A menu button appears. When the button is toggled to show the menu and then toggled to hide it again and then the window size is increased to the navbar stays hidden.
I think the jquery toggle is adding the inline style which is overriding the css

How can I stop this from happening?

```
$('#responsive_nav_trigger').click(function(){
  $('#top_nav').toggle('fast');
});

@media screen and (min-width: 760px) {
    #top_nav{
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
    #responsive_nav_trigger{
        display: block;
    }
    #top_nav{
        display: none;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        clear: both;
    }
    #top_nav li{
        width: 100%;
        height: 25px;
        font-size: 1em;
        float: left;
        margin: 5px 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use media Query for Desktop screen resolution and USE display:none; there

Comment: But is it no the jquery toggle that is doing the display:none inline, which is causing the problem?

Comment: Use !important then in display:none!important;

Comment: Provide me link to you jsfiddle

Comment: display: inline-block!important; works. Thank you

Comment: Sorry i mistakenly pasted answer in comments section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please 
Use

```
display: inline-block!important;
```